# Several applications no longer show dropdowns

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, firefox, libreoffice

After a recent update of my Kubuntu 16.04 box, some applications are crippled in terms of no longer showing essential dropdowns.

Not working:

- Firefox Menu (3 bars)
- All combo boxes in Firefox preferences
- Some combo boxes in LibreOffice dialogs, e.g., **Save as ... Filter**.
  The latter combo box can still be operated using cursor keys, though.

Working:

- Combo boxes in LibreOffice **Format** dialogs
- Combo boxes in other applications like Thunderbird and Eclipse

Is this a known bug? If so, in which component?

Am I right in assuming that all above applications are built on GTK? For that matter, could this be related to the configured GTK Theme Breeze?

Comment: Shortly after, gtk stopped respecting `gtk-alternative-button-order = 1`. Out of the blue, it seems, i.e., without me changing my configuration. Looks like the installation is beyond its best-before date.

Comment: The original problem disappeared after upgrading to 18.04.

Comment: Apparently issue of  `gtk-alternative-button-order` was unrelated after all. It remained after upgrading to 18.04.  Turned out I had to add that declaration to one more file: `.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`. Whether gtk behavior changed (stopped reading one of the many gtkrc files?), or the setting had been in the right file before and was overwritten during some update I can no longer find out.